# What kind of bird is this and what does it eat?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]
My father found this little guy in one of the tractors of where he works (in the fields) i’m not sure what species of bird it is and what it eats. It just keeps chirping not stop and I have no clue what so ever to what it eats. If anyone knows please tell me, I don’t want to see him starve to death.

Comment: Hi Maria, if you can give a general location it’ll help us give you more accurate information. Are you in the US?

Comment: when in doubt finely ground meat can work temporarily there are very few (non-mammalian) vertebrates that cannot digest meat. not a long term solution but can buy time.

Comment: Could you provide a photo showing the little guy from the side so that one can see the pattern of the wings? Would be very helpful. Frm this view I'd say that this is some sort of sparrrow

Answer (score 1):

Based on the photo, it looks like you have a fledgling **American Goldfinch** (*Spinus tristis*). Here's a photo of an adult female feeding a young goldfinch. This [link](https://www.perkypet.com/advice/bird-library/wild-bird/american-goldfinch/food-preferences) has dietary information.

[image]

I would suggest contacting your local Wildlife Rehabilitation Centre or leaving the young guy where he was found. He could of jumped the nest a bit early, but typically the parents are always nearby.